# What gate do I use to replicate period finding in Shor's algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, cryptography, quantum-computing

Recently, I have been looking into trying to replicate the popular Shor's algorithm but I have been having major difficulties... As I break this problem down into its quantum parts, there is the QFT part and then we have the phase estimation/ period finding part.

The trouble for me right now is trying to implement the period finding part. When we look at diagrams of this algorithm, we see the diagrams using a controlled-unitary operator which is then acted on by the inverse QFT to then find the period using the continued fractions. So the part I am confused about is what unitary operator I am supposed to use in the period finding part of this algorithm if I intend to replicate the algorithm on qiskit.

BTW this is the diagram I was talking about: 
[Shor's algorithm diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltbj4.png)

The part I am having trouble with is the operators at the bottom. What operators do I use to replicate the function f(x) = a^x (mod N) on qiskit. What gate do I use?

Thanks for any help!